# Postgres: integer out of range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm running the following query:

```
WITH match_team_vals(match_id, team_id, is_radiant) AS (
VALUES 
(2281450916, 2783913, true),
(2281450916, 2538753, false)
)

INSERT INTO dota_match_team(match_id, team_id, is_radiant)
SELECT match_id, team_id, is_radiant
FROM match_team_vals
RETURNING id AS lineup_id
```

on this table:

```
CREATE TABLE dota_match_team
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  match_id integer NOT NULL,
  team_id integer,
  is_radiant boolean NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT dota_match_teams_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

The error message I get is

```
ERROR: integer out of range
SQL state: 22003
```

I've tried casting the match_id and team_id to bigint. Also looking online I see that people have this issue with the serial hitting the upper limit of integers. This doesn't seem to be the case:

```
SELECT nextval('dota_match_team_id_seq')
returns 31
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider altering your table to use a bigger integer (see here for details: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html).

I think the problem is, that your `match_id` and `team_id` are of type `integer` and you try to insert the value `2281450916`, but integer's maximum is `2147483647`

Comment: Whoops. I changed all of my other ints to bigints but missed these! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can run this query:

```
ALTER TABLE dota_match_team alter column match_id type bigint;
```

this type cast solve the error for match_id. if you thinkIt is error of serial limit then you can also do.

```
  SELECT setval('dota_match_team_id_seq' , 100000000);
```