# PostgreSQL insert with nested query fails with large numbers of rows

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to insert data into a PostgreSQL table using a nested SQL statement. I'm finding that my inserts work with a small (a few thousand) rows being returned from the nested query. For instance, when I attempt:

```
insert into the_target_table (a_few_columns, average_metric)

    SELECT a_few_columns, AVG(a_metric)
    FROM a table
    GROUP BY a_few_columns LIMIT 5000)
```

However, this same query fails when I remove my `LIMIT` (the inner query without limit returns about 30,000 rows):

> ERROR: Integer out of range

`a_metric` is a double precision, and `a_few_columns` are text. I've played around with the LIMIT rows, and it seems like the # of rows it can insert without throwing an error is 14,000. I don't know if this is non-deterministic, or a constant threshold before the error is thrown.

I've looked through a few other SO posts on this topic, [including this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36513168/postgres-integer-out-of-range), and changed my table primary key data type to `BIGINT`. I still get the same error. I don't think it's an issue w/ numerical overflow, however, as the number of inserts I'm making is small and nowhere even close to hitting the threshold.

Anyone have any clues what is causing this error?

Comment: Inserting several million rows in this way (`insert ... select ...`) is not a problem. 30000 rows really cannot impress the server. You should search for a cause of the error somewhere else. Does the standalone `select` work properly? Are the types of the columns in `insert` and `select` exactly the same? (etc)

Comment: What is the data type of columns a_few_columns, average_metric in table the_target_table

Comment: @Gaj I’ve edited my question to answer your questions

Comment: is that possible that AVG(a_metric) return more than 15 decimal? can you try with round(AVG(a_metric),2) without limit

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing the definitions of all tables involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was an improper definition of the `avg_metric` field in my table that I wanted to insert it into. I accidentally had defined it as an integer. This normally isn’t a huge issue, but I also had a handful of infinity values ( `inf`). Once I switched my field data type to double precision I was able to insert successfully. Of course, it’s probably best if my application had checked beforehand for finite values prior to attempting the insert- normally I’d do this programmatically via asserts, but with a nested query I hadn’t bothered to check.

The final query I used was

insert into the_target_table (a_few_columns, average_metric)

```
SELECT a_few_columns, CASE WHEN AVG(a_metric) = 'inf' THEN NULL ELSE AVG(a_metric) END
FROM a_table
GROUP BY a_few_columns LIMIT 5000)
```

An even better solution would have been to go through `a_table` and replace all `inf` values first.